# How to Convert plain text data into managed format?

Tags: c#, xml, list, sorting

Using C#, the goal is to create a working app that will accept a text file as an input, read it,  and separate the sections of data within that text file into distinct groups that contain an index #, and the name of the section which is found in the first part of the section.

This is perhaps more of a question about how to take data in a plain text file, separate it into sections of data "groups"? and output a file in some managed format.

The text input file has 13 fields, and then an additional field for status, making 14 fields.

The text input file will have about 1500 - 2000 groups of sections of data, so there will be up to 2000 entries indexed and with the name of the entry being the first field, which is "Package Name".  A section of data will be like this:

```
Package:  horse
Version:  1.2.3
Depends:  libgcc
Provides:
Status:  user installed
Other:   other info
Other2:  other info 2

Package:  cow
Version:  2.3.4
Depends:  libhay
Provides: milk
Status:   user installed
Other:    white with black spots
Other2:   has a red cow bell around her neck

Package:  tractor
Version:  0.9.22
Depends:  diesel
Provides:
```

etc...

How can the data be read and placed into appropriate tables or entries or datasets?

ps thanks for the previous edit

Comment: Looks like it'd be perfect for a dictionary. All you'd have to do is split it at the `:`

Comment: I'd ordinarily hate to suggest using XML when a plain text file would do, but there's good support in .NET for deserializing XML data into runtime data structures...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simplistic solution would just be to read the file one line at a time, splitting at the ":" and storing each in a `Dictionary<string, string>` which itself is stored in a `Package` and adding it to a `List<Package>`. Whenever you get a keyword "Package", create a new `Package` instance and add it to the list. The code below does the trick, but is not very defensively coded.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      string line;
      List<Package> packages = new List<Package>();
      Package package = null;
      StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("TextFile1.txt");
      while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
      {
        string[] pair = line.Split(new string[] { ": " }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        if (pair.Length != 2)
          continue;
        if (pair[0] == "Package")
        {
          package = new Package();
          packages.Add(package);
        }
        package.Values.Add(pair[0].Trim(), pair[1].Trim());
      }
      file.Close();
      Console.WriteLine(packages.Count);
      foreach (Package p in packages)
      {
        Console.WriteLine(p);
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in p.Values)
          Console.WriteLine("{0}={1}", pair.Key, pair.Value);
      }
      Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }

  class Package
  {
    public Dictionary<string, string> Values;
    public Package()
    {
      Values = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }
  }
```

Comment: GREAT!  I put this into the code and it works as expected thanks!  what i had done was make an array and split the data; but I am hoping to find the newest ways using the latest styles to do this.  Never had to use a Dictionary before.  but its running fine on the smaller file thats 9K in size, it parses it perfectly.  i opened another thats 950K and the cpu has been at 80-100% for several minutes.  just checked, still says "not responding".  it can take a couple minutes, but now Im wondering if it needs to have some activity monitor on the GUI...